# check if two bytes are symmetric

Tags: java, byte, symmetric, symmetry

I heard this is a question asked in an interview, given two bytes, return true if they are symmetric

```
public boolean isSym(Byte firstByte, Byte secondByte);
```

01101000 and 00010110 are symmetric, 
but 01100000 and 11000000 are not.
need to write the code in Java.
Any ideas what is the best way to do so?

Comment: Wrong tag, you used javascript, should be java

Comment: @aximus already fixed.

Comment: There are various ways here to reverse a bit sequence: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean isSym(Byte firstByte, Byte secondByte)
{

    for (int i = 0; i< 8 ; i++){
        if (bitAt(firstByte, i) != bitAt(secondByte, 7 - i))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public byte bitAt(byte num, int position)
{
   return (byte)((num >> position) & (byte)1);
}
```